# Display top n values based on count and not on alphabets dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have tried using the code below to display the top 3 values based on the count of the **val** in the json provided below.

```
yearRingChart.width(300).height(300).dimension(yearDim).group(
                spendPertime).innerRadius(50).controlsUseVisibility(true)
                .data(function(d) {
                return d.order(
                 function(d) {
                    return d.val;
                }).top(3);
            }).ordering(function(d) {
                return -d.val;
            });
```

But this is getting sorted based on alphabetical order and not based on **val**.
I need to display the top 3 names with highest val in the json provided.

The code snippet is provided below -

```
var yearRingChart = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-year"), 
        spendHistChart = dc.barChart("#chart-hist-spend"), 
        spenderRowChart = dc.rowChart("#chart-row-spenders");                               
        var table = dc.dataTable('#table');
        // use static or load via d3.csv("spendData.csv", function(error, spendData) {/* do stuff */});
        var spendData = [{
            Name : 'A',
            val : '100',
            time : 9,
            place : 'Kolkata'
        }, {
            Name : 'B',
            val : '40',
            time : 10,
            place : 'Angalore'
        }, {
            Name : 'C',
            val : '5',
            time : 11,
            place : 'Raipur'

        }, {
            Name : 'A',
            val : '70',
            time : 12,
            place : 'Chennai'
        }, {
            Name : 'B',
            val : '20',
            time : 10,
            place : 'Mumbai'
        }];
        // normalize/parse data
        spendData.forEach(function(d) {         
            d.val = d.val.match(/\d+/)[0];
        });
        // set crossfilter
        var ndx = crossfilter(spendData), yearDim =
ndx.dimension(function(
                d) {
            return d.place;
        }), spendDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
            return Math.floor(d.val / 10);
        }), nameDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
            return d.Name;

        }), spendPertime = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
            return +d.val;
        })
        , spendPerSev = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
            return +d.val;
        }), spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {

            return +d.val;


        }), spendHist = spendDim.group().reduceCount();


        yearRingChart.width(300).height(300).dimension(yearDim).group(
                spendPertime).innerRadius(50).controlsUseVisibility(true)
                .data(function(d) {
                return d.order(
                 function(d) {
                    return d.val;
                }).top(3);
            }).ordering(function(d) {
                return -d.ue;
            });
```

I am a newbie in dc.js. Any help will be appreciated.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the big problem you are running into is that [`.ordering()`](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#ordering__anchor) - which is the right way to do this - takes group data, not raw data. Once you have aggregated your data using a group, you are going to have an array of `{key,value}` pairs, not your original array of data.

So I think when you attempt to read `d.val` or `d.ue`, you're just getting `undefined`, which results in no sorting. You could verify this by putting a breakpoint or `console.log` in your `ordering` callbacks. That's how I usually debug these kinds of things, when I have a running example.

`group.order` isn't going to have much effect, so I would suggest removing that.

I'd also suggest using [.cap()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.capMixin.html#cap__anchor) instead of that complicated data-order-top thing you have, which looks complicated / delicate. Capping is built-in functionality for pie charts and row charts.